# Can I create react native code on a server to send to client

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have created a api with node and instead of sending JSON data im sending HTML and creating elements with javascript this is quicker than sending JSON, I want to do a similar process with react native and return elements, the elements need to be clickable and I'm working with functional components, I don't want to set the value of the elements I want to dynamically create the elements so `<Text>{stateFilter}</Text>` won't work for me.

Here is my React native code

```
export default function Productdetails(categoryData) 
{  
    const categoryID = categoryData.route.params.id;
    const specifics = categoryData.route.params.specifics
    const [stateFilter, setFilter] = useState("");
    async function apiCallMain(categoryID, specifics) 
    { 
        try 
        {
            fetch('https://myapi.com/mobileGetGrid', 
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: 
                { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({id: categoryID, specifics: specifics}),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>
            {
                //Here is when call is finished and return <Text>Element From Server</Text>
                setFilter(data[1])
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
        } 
        catch(err) 
        {
           console.error("Failed to log in", err);
        }    
    }
    await apiCallMain(categoryID, specifics); 
    return (   
        <View>
        {stateFilter}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Here is the NodeJS code.

```
apiRoutes.route('/mobileGetGrid').post(function(req, res) 
{
    var strcategory_id = req.id;
    const queryObj = {};
    queryObj["c"] = strcategory_id;
    var productJSON= await Databaseproducts.find(queryObj);
    var finalJSONObject = new Array();
    finalJSONObject.push(productJSON);
    var rnElements = "<Text>Element From Server</Text>";
    finalJSONObject.push(rnElements);
    parentPort.postMessage(finalJSONObject);
}
```